# CSS unexpected behaviour, margin applied to parent tag when defined in child

Tags: html, css

I am trying to push the parent to the top of the page so it will not show the white area on the top, but the child seems to be pushing the parent down. Why is this?

Here is the jsfiddle page:

http://jsfiddle.net/vy3pgvfe/

here is the Html:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- main content area -->
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div id="main-content">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                         <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

                        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
                    </div>
                    <button id="show-sidebar">sidebar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- col-sm-9 -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
</body>

</html>
```

and the css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;

}

.container {
    width: 100%;  
    height: 100%;   
    background-color:red;   
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-sm-9 {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
}

#main-content {
    background-color: rgba(45, 30, 90, 0.5);
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: you are experiencing [collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Do you need a margin for the child, or do you want it on the very top?

Comment: @web-tiki: I'm reading that page now.only the child.

Comment: @rp.beltran: I want the page to be fully red and only the child to have the margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [collapsing margin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) issue can be fixed by adding `overflow:auto` to `.col-sm-9`:

```
.col-sm-9 {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(190, 190, 190, 0.5);
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vy3pgvfe/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 5px;` will add margins to all 4 sides of the box, giving your 5pixels of whitespace. You probably want

```
margin: 5px;
margin-top: 0px;
```

or

```
margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
```

to eliminate the margin on top of the box.

Comment: But I do want the child to have a margin of 5px, but only have the margin applied in relative to the parent. Meaning, I want it to have a margin and show red on the top instead of white. But more importantly I want to understand why this is happening.

Comment: none of the parents have any content, so the 5px all-around margin you're apply will basically get applied to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the outside padding, and remove the inside margin. It should work in the same way.

```
.container {

    width: 100%;

    height: 100%;

    background-color:red;
    padding-top:5px;

}

#main-content {

    background-color: rgba(45, 30, 90, 0.5);

    margin: 0px;

    padding: 5px;

}
```

Comment: this seems to be pushing the content to the right of the screen so now there is a scroll bar at the bottom.

Comment: Just use padding-top: 5px; for container.